# Unity external collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Is there a clean way to do ExternalColliders for the main game object?**

I have the **MainObject with no Collider**. MainObject have **ChildObjects that have collider(s)**. Some **Random Scripts** do a raycast and need to get a MainObject.

- Scene

  - MainObject *(with no collider)*

    - ChildObject *(visual prefab with collider(s))*
  - RandomScripts *(does raycast, need to get parentObject)*

I can use transform.parent, but if I have a structure like MainObject > Object > ... > ObjectWithCollider, it won't work. Is there a proper way to get ParentObject for any raycast, without knowledge that *"Use transform.parent of this collider, or you just get visual prefab of main game object!"*?

---

My problem is: I have a lot of different prefabs of 2D enemies with different colliders. In example, I have an enemy like:

> - Main Object
>
>   - Visual prefab
>
>     - Right Leg (with Collider)
>     - Left Leg (with Collider)
>     - Body (with Collider)

An explosion happens, and I want to all objects with interface/component IHealth take damage in some radius. When I do raycast I can get Right Leg collider, but it is just a visual prefab without any logic. I want to do raycastCollider.GetComponent< IHealth> and get Main Object IHealth component...

Right now, my soulution is: an interface/component with only one field: MainCollider. When I do raycast, I always use GetComponent.ParentCollider. But is there a way to always get ParentObject with raycast without using SomeInterface?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to get the base/root GameObject, and you can use the [Transform.root property for that](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-root.html):

> **Description**
>
> Returns the topmost transform in the hierarchy.
>
> (This never returns null, if this Transform doesn't have a parent it returns itself.)

So if you're doing raycasting, you'd get the `RaycastHit hit` and then could poll the collider for the root GameObject, like:

```
GameObject rootGO = hit.collider.transform.root.gameObject;
```

Comment: Good idea, didn't know about transform.root. But I very often face the need to create a collider on the Child object in asset or game part. I am wondering how it is done on other projects, when client shouldn't know about: "Hey, use *this logic* when raycast, or it won't work"

Comment: @AlexTerkov - Ah then maybe you can use [GetComponentInParent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInParent.html), which would try to get a Component like a MonoBehaviour in the object itself and then starts recursing UP the transform chain looking for that component.